# Unexpected repeated collisions in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making my first game with Swift and SpriteKit and while I've had collisions working properly for some time now, I recently noticed a huge bug. My collisions can either be the user with and enemy (spaceship against alien) user shooting an enemy (laser against alien). The latter works fine, but recently the collision detection when the ship touches an alien hasn't been working-- normally the alien should be removed from the scene when it touches the so that only a single life (1 of 3 total) is removed. However, the ship looses 3-6 lives upon touch now. Here's the code and where I'd assume the problem is:

This is one of a few contact functions that is then called in the general contact method.

```
func alien_ship_contact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){
    var alien:SKNode? = nil

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Alien && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Ship{
        alien = contact.bodyA.node

    }
    else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Alien && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Ship{
        alien = contact.bodyB.node

    }
    else{
        return
    }

    killOffAlien((alien)!)
    aliensKilled = aliensKilled + 1
    shipLives = shipLives-1
    aShip.lives = aShip.lives - 1

    print("ship/alien contact")
}
```

Here is the `killOffAlien` function:

```
func killOffAlien(alien:SKNode){

    print("Kill off")
    //alien.removeFromParent()


    func stopMotion(){
        alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        alien.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0

        alien.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        alien.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx:0, dy:0)
        alien.removeActionForKey("facialMotion")
    }


    func removeAlien(){
        alien.removeFromParent()
    }

    let stopMoving = SKAction.runBlock(stopMotion)

    let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(1)
    let removeFromParent = SKAction.runBlock(removeAlien)

    let die = SKAction.sequence([stopMoving, fadeOut, removeFromParent])

    alien.runAction(die)
}
```

And here is the general contact method:

```
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact){
    alien_laser_contact(contact)
    alien_ship_contact(contact)
    ....
```

Any help would be awesome, I would think that upon initial contact the alien has it's bitmask set off from `Alien` so that in itself would prevent future collisions as every alien should only be able to remove at max one life from the ship.

Comment: Just because you call remove from parent, does not mean the object dies at that point.  Also, your body can collide with other bodies at various points, so multiple collisions can happen.  You need to set your code up to not process anymore after you signal your sprite to die

Comment: side note,  using _ is bad,  your names should be alienLaserContact and alienShipContact.  see https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: To add on to what Knight0fDragon said and what he meant by reference, something like that happened to me. I used SKSpriteNodes as buttons before, and after removing them from their parent, the action was still being called whenever I would touch the spot that used to have the button despite no button being present. I fixed it by declaring them as nil when I didn't need them, but ultimately fixed it by making my own custom button class for SpriteKit.

Comment: @knight0fDragon I'll look through the style guide now-- I should have consistency. As far as ending the processing, would you suggest using a boolean value to do a check? As in setting dead = true for that specific instance and then checking it with an if upon the next collision? Or is there a standard for this sort of thing? thanks!

Comment: Search my name in the search tool,  you will see many answers by me on how to handle your problem, I am sure one of those situations will help you out.